# Hover not disappearing when using Sortable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following script, which works fine in Chrome but not in IE8:

**jQuery:**

```
$("<div class='divButtons'></div>").appendTo( $(".widget_header") );
$(".divButtons").text("321");
```

**CSS:**

```
.divButtons { background:orange; display:none; }
.widget:hover .divButtons { display:block; }
```

**jsFiddle:**

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/GM83C/1/) of the full thing.

**What works:**

What happens is, when I hover over a `.widget`, the css causes the `.divButtons` to display.  All good so far.  When I move a `.widget` to another `.widget` and let go, the `.widget`s change places, and the `.widget` which I am hovering over still displays the `.divButtons`, all is well.  If I `mouseout` of a `.widget` and `hover` over another `.widget`, the `.divButtons` disappears from the `.widget`which I was `hover`ing over and appears on the `.widget` I am `hover`ing over.  All good so far.

**The problem:**

The problem in IE8, which doesn't happen in Chrome, is when I `hover` over a `.widget`, which causes the `.divButtons` to appear on the `.widget` I am `hover`ing over.  If I then move that `.widget` to a `white` part of the screen and then let go, I am no longer `hover`ing over the `.widget`, but the `.divButtons` is still showing on the `.widget` I just let go of.

This should not be happening.  This works fine in Chrome as I've mentioned before.

**The question:**

Any way to get this to work correctly in IE8 as it is currently working in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems IE8 has a bug that *mouseout* or *mouseleave* are never fired on an element when the element is moved out from under the mouse scope. As a result `:hover` is never removed, and all the mouseout, hoverleave, etc event listeners in jquery will not be called.

What I've come up with is to check if any `.column` is being hovered when a `.widget` is realeased. If no columns are being hovered, we remove the hover state from the widget.

I've used a `.hover` class on `.widget` to maintain this as we can't remove `:hover` using jquery.

**jsFiddle**

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GM83C/11/) of the working fix.

**CSS**

```
.widget.hover .divButtons { display:block; }​
```

**jQuery**

```
// We use this rather than :hover as :hover didn't always work in ie
$('.column').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});

// This is our base widget hover code
$('.widget').hover(function() {
    $('.widget.hover').removeClass('hover');
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

**jQuery sortable call**

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    // We use stop to call this when the widget has been dropped
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // We wait 1 millisecond until after the widget is dropped
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Check if any widget is hovered. Good browsers will have 0 here and skip the following. IE8 will have 1 here
            if ($('.widget.hover').size() > 0) {
                // We check if the widgets parent column does not has hover
                if (!$('.widget.hover').first().parent().is('.hover')) {
                    // If no column hover. We remove this hover class
                    $('.widget.hover').removeClass('hover');
                }
            }
        }, 1);
    }
});
```

I hope this works for you.

It's so annoying that in 2012 we still have to make such difficult work arounds because versions of IE have such bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead over using `hover` pseudo class can you try this

CSS

```
.widget.hover  .divButtons { display:block; }​
```

JS

```
$('.widget').hover(function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('hover');
},function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer can't really be trusted when it comes to applying hover styles on anything but anchors.

Apparently, it doesn't redraw an item when moved across the DOM nor does it reset the hover state unless the mouse enters the area again. To fix this, you can clone the dragged item instead of using the item directly.

The `sortable()` method has an easy option for that:

```
$( ".column" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".column",
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    helper: 'clone' // added
});
```

Comment: This works as long as the update event is fired. I need it to work even if the update event isn't fired, i.e. when a .widget is dragged, but it ends up being dropped back to its' original location. When this happens, the update event isn't fired.

Comment: The stop event should always fire though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use `stop` either.  Because it stops working parts from working, i.e. with the original script, moving a `.widget` to another `.widget`'s position where the mouse still hovers over the dropped widget would not remove the `.divButtons`.  But with the `stop`, as soon as you drop a `.widget`, the `.divButtons` disappear, even if you are still hovering on the `.widget`.  You have to move the mouse a little for the `.divButtons` to re-appear.  So basically, I am looking for a solution which does not break the existing script's functionality.

Comment: @oshirowanen Thanks to your comments, I found that the solution is much easier ... just clone the dragged element :)

Comment: Maybe I am not using the `clone` properly, but I've just tried it and it seems to have a similar effect as `stop`, i.e. the `.divButtons` keeps disappearing when it shouldn't.

Comment: @oshirowanen If it helps, this works fine under IE for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GM83C/9/

Comment: Just tried your #9 example, and it almost seems perfect in jsFiddle with IE8, but when I copy the same script into a HTML file and run it from my server, the `.divButtons` keeps doing a disappearing act on drag and drops where a `.widget` is dropped a few pixels from its original location, i.e. if the `.widget` is not dragged far enough for it to be completely surrounded by white space before dropped, which causes it to end up in it's original location.

Comment: @oshirowanen I'm sorry, but I don't experience that; it only hides the buttons when there's scrolling involved, but that's a more lower level issue I think; perhaps that could be salvaged by using a dragging class (i.e. a css class that's assigned when an element is being dragged)

Comment: hmm, I'm wondering why I would be experiencing this issue when I am using nothing but the script in your example jsfiddle, with IE8?

Comment: As a disclaimer, I'm using IE8 mode within IE9; but without the clone option, I get the same behaviour though.

Comment: IC, I am using pure IE8, not IE8 mode within IE9 and this solution does not seem to work for me.  So far the original script I posted had the least amount of issues.  All other examples I have tried from this question have had more issues than the original in true IE8.

Comment: You also mentioned it works okay inside the fiddle, so I'm not sure what to make of this without seeing the actual page you're using it in.

Comment: To see what I am seeing, you just have to get the code from jsFiddle and stick it into a standard HTML file and navigate to the file on a webserver using true IE8.

Comment: @oshirowanen I've tried that (copy the source from the fiddle window into a fresh page), but there's no difference from running it inside the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Got nearly the same problem with IE9. Jack's right, it frequently gets stuck in a hover state if DOM element was changed before mouseout happened.

I couldn't find a solid fix for this kind of behavior, so I switched to jQuery `.hover()` instead of `:hover` pseudoclass, like this:

```
$(elt).hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("jHover");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("jHover");
});
```

It's far more reliable, though not so cool, yes.

Comment: This seems to produce exactly the same results as the original problem I had.

Comment: well, then I can't think of anything but a crude workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/GVuC6/

Comment: I've just tried your latest example in true IE8, not an emulated IE8 via IE9 and it does not work.  If I move a `.widget` by a few pixels and let go after which I don't move the mouse which means it is still hovering over the dropped `.widget`, the `.divButtons` disappears, until the mouse moves again.  This was not a problem which happened with the original script I posted.